# Javascript file "FASW transitions" duplicating my header info. How to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, css

Ok! I'm working on a wordpress site, and everything this javascript add on is supposed to do, it does...But, when I inspect element via safari develop, I notice that it's loading all of my headers scripts,meta,styles etc. into the body as well as the head. I can't figure out why. Here's what the script looks like:

```
function ft(params) {

var ol= document.addEventListener?"DOMContentLoaded":"load"; //on load event
var navB = params.navB || "reverse slide"; //backbrowser button effect, default empty
var but = params.but || false; //Allow transitions on input type button
var cBa = params.cBa || function() {};

function aDL(url, t, o) {   //Ajax Div Load
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (r != undefined) {
    r.onreadystatechange = function() {Ol(r, t, o);};
    r.open("GET", url, true);
    r.send("");
  }
}  
function Ol(r, t, o) {  //On load div
  if (r.readyState == 4) { 
    if (r.status == 200 || r.status == 0) { 
      t.innerHTML = r.responseText;
      o();
    } else {
      t.innerHTML="Error:\n"+ r.status + "\n" +r.statusText;
    }
  }
}

    function DE()       //Div Effect
{
var dochtml = document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML = "";
var d1 = document.createElement("div");
d1.id = "d1";
d1.style.zIndex = 2;
d1.style.position = "absolute"; 
d1.style.width = "100%"; 
d1.style.height = "100%"; 
d1.style.left = "0px"; 
d1.style.top = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(d1);
d1.innerHTML = dochtml;
var d2 = document.createElement("div");
d2.id = "d2";
d2.style.zIndex = 1;
d2.style.position = "absolute"; 
d2.style.width = "100%"; 
d2.style.height = "100%"; 
d2.style.left = "0px"; 
d2.style.top = "0px";
document.body.appendChild(d2);
return {d1: d1, d2: d2 };
}

function timeOuts(e, d1,d2)
{
setTimeout(function() { d1.className = e + " out"; }, 1);
setTimeout(function() { d2.className = e + " in"; }, 1);
setTimeout(function() { 
    document.body.innerHTML = d2.innerHTML;
    cBa();
}, 706);
}

function slideTo(href, effect, pushstate)
{
var d = DE();
var d1 = d.d1;
var d2 = d.d2;
aDL(href, d2, 
function() {
if (pushstate && window.history.pushState) window.history.pushState("", "", href);
            timeOuts(effect,d1,d2);
        }
);
}
function dC(e){ //Detect click event
var o;
var o=e.srcElement || e.target;
var tn = o.tagName.toLowerCase();
if (!but || tn!="input" || o.getAttribute("type")!="button")    //if it is not a button
{
    //try to find an anchor parent
    while (tn!=="a" && tn!=="body")
    {
        o = o.parentNode;
        tn = o.tagName.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (tn==="body") return;
}
var t = o.getAttribute("data-ftrans");
if (t) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var hr = o.getAttribute("href") || o.getAttribute("data-href");
    if (hr) slideTo(hr, t, true);
}
}
function aE(ev, el, f) {  //Add event
if (el.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
    el.addEventListener(ev,f,false);
else if (el.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
     var r = el.attachEvent("on"+ev, f);
     return r;
}
}
aE("click", window, dC);

aE(ol, document,        //On load
function(ev)
{
aE("popstate", window, function(e) {    //function to reload when back button   is clicked
        slideTo(location.pathname, navB, false);
});
}

);


}
```

here is the link to the site: http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/

I assume that thats not supposed to happen. So im trying to figure out how to keep it clean, and keep the head files loaded in the head, and only load the page content. I cannot figure this one out, some help from the pros is needed :)

Answer (score 0):

FASW comes with two functions that serves as "hooks" both before and after initializing the component. you can do it like this:

```
(function inittrans() 
{
    initComponents();
    var params = { /*put your options here*/ };
    new ft(params);
})();

function onTransitionFinished()
{
    initComponents();
}

function initComponents() {
    // here is where you put your "other" javascript codes
}
```

Notice how your javascript codes are executed after loading your initial page and once again after the transition happened. Anyway, this is how I got the work around on it 'coz javascript codes just won't work as they are loaded by FASW via Ajax on-the-fly.